# MySQL Pivot Table Dynamic Rows

Tags: mysql

I need your help.

I have a table like the one below;

`+-------+-----------+-----------+-----+--------+-------------+
| grade | firstname | lastname  | age | gender | student_num |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----+--------+-------------+
|     2 | Stephen   | Harper    |  12 | male   |           1 |
|     1 | Jennifer  | Solomon   |  10 | female |           1 |
|     4 | James     | Barney    |   9 | female |           1 |
|     3 | Collins   | Balmer    |   8 | female |           1 |
|     4 | Kehinde   | Adefemi   |  12 | male   |           2 |
|     2 | Benjamin  | Salem     |  14 | female |           2 |
|     3 | Praise    | Olawale   |   9 | male   |           2 |
|     1 | Janet     | Pelumi    |   7 | male   |           2 |
|     3 | Ire       | Adora     |  11 | female |           3 |
|     2 | Manny     | Grace     |  13 | male   |           3 |
|     2 | Esther    | Benson    |   7 | female |           4 |
|     3 | Stan      | Collimore |   6 | female |           4 |`

Please help me with the SQL that will generate the resulting table below from the one above.

`grade|s1_fname  |s1_age|s1_gender|s2_fname |s2_age|s2_gender
  1  | Jennifer | 10   |female   | Janet   | 7    |  male  |
  2  | Stephen  | 12   |male     | Benjamin| 14   |  female|
  3  | Collins  | 8    |female   | Praise  | 9    |  male  |
  4  | Kehinde  | 12   |male     | Myedan  | 8    |  male  |`

where s1 means student1. The 1 should be gotten from from student_num column

where s2 means student2. The 2 should be gotten from from student_num column
...

Also my database server is MySQL.

Thanks!

I Learned such tables are called PIVOT tables.

I Have tried the code below

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
          'SUM(CASE WHEN `grade` = ',
          `grade`,
          ' THEN firstname ELSE 0 END) AS `s',
          `student_num`, '_fname`'
        )
    ) INTO @sql
FROM students;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT grade, ', @sql, ' FROM students GROUP BY grade');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: You should post some code you tried.

Comment: @OP: You better pivot the `grade`s but not student details

Comment: @HonzaHaering, i have edited the question showing the codes i have tried. Thanks.

Comment: @Ravinder how do i pivot the grades column, see my edit and the code i have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s1.grade, s1.firstname AS s1_fname, s1.age AS s1_age, s1.gender AS s1_gender, 
       s2.firstname AS s2_fname, s2.age AS s2_age, s2.gender AS s2_gender
FROM students s1 JOIN students s2 ON s1.student_num = 1 
     AND s2.student_num = 2 AND s1.grade = s2.grade
ORDER BY s1.grade;
```

Comment: what if we have 20 students in grade 1? How do i carry out the dynamic column creation since we might not know the number of students in a grade before hand?

Comment: Then I wouldn't go this way of creating dynamic columns. Why do you need it in columns?

Comment: **@user3142200**: You better pivot the `'grade'`s but not student details

Comment: Thanks @Honza for your post. I need it in column because we need to GROUP BY the grade column. The final destination is a CSV file, we want all students for any grade to be on a single row. its a client request.